# highlighting plot with POSIXt format values

Tags: r, plot, highlight

I have a plot with time (POSIXt) format values in y axis. I need to highlight a portion but in order to define the rect values, but i need also to highlight the all y axis (to make a highlight box covering all the y axis).

```
DF <- data.frame(DOY = 1:23, Photoperiod = 
c("8:52:41","8:53:35","8:54:33","8:55:36","8:56:44","8:57:55","8:59:11",
"9:00:31","9:01:55","9:03:23","9:04:55","9:06:31","9:08:10","9:09:53",
"9:11:40","9:13:30","9:15:23","9:17:20","9:19:20","9:21:23","9:23:29",
"9:25:38","9:27:49"))

DOY Photoperiod
1   08:52:41
2   08:53:35
3   08:54:33
4   08:55:36
5   08:56:44
6   08:57:55
7   08:59:11
8   09:00:31
9   09:01:55
10  09:03:23
11  09:04:55
12  09:06:31
13  09:08:10
14  09:09:53
15  09:11:40
16  09:13:30
17  09:15:23
18  09:17:20
19  09:19:20
20  09:21:23
21  09:23:29
22  09:25:38
23  09:27:49

DF<-as.POSIXct(DF$Photoperiod, format = "%H:%M:%S") 
i<- min(DF) 
b<- max(DF)

plot(DF, type="l")
box()
rect(4,i,10,b, col= 'lightgreen', density=65)
```

Comment: What's `DF.Php` and what is an 'al y axis'? I do not understand what you are trying to highlight here.

Comment: I edited my question. now i have the highlight but it is not covering all the length of y axis.